# Remove margin on inside of R plot

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot return against date, and I would like the line to start and end at the line border. The plot code I am using -

```
minX = min(hf_instl$date)
maxX = max(hf_instl$date)
plot(df$date, cumsum(df$return), type = "l", col = rgb(0, 0.447, 0.741), xlim = c(minX, maxX), ylim = c(minY, maxY), yaxt = "n", xlab = NA, ylab = NA)
```

What I get is this -

[image: Plot]

Any solution to this in the base plot package? `ggplot2` solutions are also okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `xaxs` property for that:

```
# create some fake data for the example
hf_instl = data.frame(date=seq(Sys.Date()-200,Sys.Date(),by='day'),return=runif(201,-1,1.5))
df = hf_instl    
minX = min(hf_instl$date)
maxX = max(hf_instl$date)
minY=0
maxY=sum(df$return)+10


# your plot
plot(df$date, cumsum(df$return), type = "l", col = rgb(0, 0.447, 0.741), 
    xlim = c(minX, maxX), ylim = c(minY, maxY), yaxt = "n", 
    xlab = NA, ylab = NA,xaxs='i')
```

[image]

Hope this helps!